# Bukkit Plugin: Can't import command

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I started working on a bukkit plugin the other day with the aim to return hello in the text window when the user types in '/hello'. However this is not working, because I cannot import the command line in eclipse. Any suggestions? It says, "Command cannot be resolved to a type"

```
package me.Nickedyerpants;

import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Plugin extends JavaPlugin{

@Override
public void onEnable(){     //what happens when plugin is enabled

    getLogger().info("First plugin starting up....");


}


@Override
public void onDisable(){   //for when plugin is disabled


    boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args){

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("hello") && sender instanceof Player){

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            player.sendMessage("hello");

        }

        return true;

    }



}

}
```

Comment: The part i cant indent is "Command cmd"

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately, it did not work, I still get syntax errors on the brackets and commas for some reason, and i am using the latest bukkit jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is inccorect, you cannot implement `onCommand` inside of the `onDisable` method, plus you need to properly close your class with a curly bracket.

Your class should look like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {   
            // plugin is being disabled.
    }


    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("hello") && sender instanceof Player) {

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            player.sendMessage("hello");

        }

        return true;

    }
```

While making sure to close the class with a closing curly bracket `}`.

*Tip: Defining methods should be within the class itself not inside another method.*